# Fedora 20: How to navigate to Windows partitions via commandline?

Tags: fedora, mount, gnome-terminal

In Fedora 16, when accessing the Windows partitions via the Fedora GUI, it would get mounted on `/media/`. They were visible as `/media/Data` etc and I was able to navigate into those partitions via the terminal. But now I see the partitions mounted on the GUI, but they're not visible in `/media/`. Could you help with navigating to the partitions via the terminal?

Or to put it in another way: Where do the Windows partitions get mounted to, when mounted via the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora uses as standard the gnome desktop. Gnome uses a virtual file system called [gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), to represent network shares. They are not mounted to a specific mount point. If you want to browse those mounts via terminal you have to use the gvfs tools (`gvfs-*`).

If your partitions are mounted the old way then just type `mount` to find out where they are mounted.

Comment: Thanks! Typing 'mount' helped. The new location where it gets mounted is in `/run/media/<username>/Data`, where 'Data' is the name of my Windows `H:` drive.